# ELF Shared Object in x86-64 Assembly language

Tags: gcc, assembly, linker, shared-libraries, x86-64

I'm trying to create a Shared library (*.so) in ASM and I'm not sure that i do it correct...

My code is:

```
    .section .data
    .globl var1
var1:
    .quad     0x012345

    .section .text
    .globl func1
func1:
    xor %rax, %rax
  # mov var1, %rcx       # this is commented
    ret
```

To compile it i run

```
gcc ker.s -g -fPIC -m64 -o ker.o
gcc ker.o -shared -fPIC -m64 -o libker.so
```

I can access variable var1 and call func1 with dlopen() and dlsym() from a program in C.

The problem is in variable var1. When i try to access it from func1, i.e. uncomment that line, the compiler generates an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ker.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `var1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
ker.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand. I've already compiled with -fPIC, so what's wrong?

Comment: Add a global function that returns the address of var1 instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually there is already a pointer variable which holds the address of var1, it's called `var1@GOTCREL` and it's reachable with rip relative position independent code.

Comment: Related: [Call a function in another object file without using PLT within a shared library?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51573771) for calling functions in other object files (but not in other shared libraries).  You also want `.hidden` for those

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i think i found something...

First solution from *drhirsch* gives almost the same error but the relocation type is changed. And type is always ended with 32. Why is it? Why 64 bit program uses 32-bit relocation?

I found this from googling: http://www.technovelty.org/code/c/relocation-truncated.html

It says:

> For code optimisation purposes, the default immediate size to the mov
>   instructions is a 32-bit value

So that's the case. I use 64-bit program but relocation is 32-bit and all i need is to force it to be 64 bit with `movabs` instruction.

This code is assembling and working (access to `var1` from internal function `func1` and from external C program via `dlsym()`):

```
    .section .data 
    .globl var1 
var1: 
    .quad     0x012345

    .section .text 
    .globl func1 
func1: 
    movabs var1, %rax       # if one is symbol, other must be %rax
    inc %rax
    movabs %rax, var1
    ret
```

But i'm in doubt about Global Offset Table. Must i use it, or this "direct" access is absolutely correct?

Comment: `movabs` will work, but this is the so called _large code model_. It is limited because you can use only `rax` and no other addressing modes.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz, `movabs` works fine for `%rsi` and `%rdx` [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/PCFGWA7i)

Comment: @IvanBlack: you're using `movabs $imm64, %r64`, which is available for any register.  This code is using the load-into-al/ax/eax/rax from 64-bit absolute address (`moffs`) form (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov), which only has one opcode for RAX, not for each possible register (8 opcodes, the REX.W form of 5-byte `mov $imm32, %r32` with no ModRM byte).

Answer (score 15):

> I've already compiled with -fPIC, so what's wrong?

That part of the error message is for people who are linking compiler-generated code.

You're writing asm by hand, so as datenwolf correctly wrote, when writing a shared library in assembly, you have to take care for yourself that the code is position independent.

This means file must not contain any 32-bit absolute addresses (because relocation to an arbitrary 64-bit base is impossible).  64-bit absolute relocations *are* supported, but normally you should only use that for jump tables.

---

**`mov var1, %rcx` uses a 32-bit absolute addressing mode**.  You should normally never do this, even in position-dependent x86-64 code.  The normal use-cases for 32-bit absolute addresses are:  putting an address into a 64-bit register with`mov $var1, %edi` (zero-extends into RDI)
and indexing static arrays: `mov arr(,%rdx,4), %edx`

**`mov var1(%rip), %rcx` uses a RIP-relative 32-bit offset**.  It's the efficient way to address static data, and compilers always use this even without `-fPIE` or `-fPIC` for static/global variables.

You have basically two possibilities:

- **Normal library-private static data**, like C compilers will make for `__attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) long var1;`, **same as for `-fno-PIC`**.

  ```
  .data
      .globl var1       # linkable from other .o files in the same shared object / library
      .hidden var1      # not visible for *dynamic* linking outside the library
  var1:
      .quad     0x012345

  .text
      .globl func1
  func1:
      xor  %eax, %eax             # return 0
      mov  var1(%rip), %rcx   
      ret
  ```
- **full symbol-interposition-aware code like compilers generate for `-fPIC`**.

  You have to use the Global Offset Table. This is how a compiler does it, if you tell him to produce code for a shared library.
  Note that this comes with a performance hit because of the additional indirection.

  See [Sorry state of dynamic libraries on Linux](https://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/) for more about symbol-interposition and the overheads it imposes on code-gen for shared libraries if you're not careful about restricting symbol visibility to allow inlining.

  `var1@GOTPCREL` is the address of a pointer to your `var1`, the pointer itself is reachable with rip-relative addressing, while the content (the address of `var1`) is filled by the linker during loading of the library.  This supports the case where the program using your library defined `var1`, so `var1` in your library should resolve to that memory location instead of the one in the `.data` or `.bss` (or `.text`) of your `.so`.

  ```
      .section .data
      .globl var1
      # without .hidden
  var1:
      .quad     0x012345

      .section .text
      .globl func1
  func1:
      xor %eax, %eax
      mov var1@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rcx
      mov (%rcx), %rcx
      ret
  ```

See some additional information at http://www.bottomupcs.com/global_offset_tables.html

[An example on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'__attribute__((visibility(%22hidden%22)))+int+x+%3D+123%3B+//+.data+section+/+DATA+segment%0Aint+y+%3D+456%3B+++//+same+but+not+%22hidden%22%0A%0Aint+getx()+%7B+return+x%3B+%7D%0Aconst+int+*getxaddr()+%7B+return+%26x%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+gety()+%7B+return+y%3B+%7D%0Aconst+int+*getyaddr()+%7B+return+%26y%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0Aconst+int+z+%3D+789%3B++++++++//+can+still+fill+in+the+value+as+an+immediate%0Aint+getz()+%7B+return+z%3B+%7D++//+even+though+it!'s+not+%22hidden%22'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.669774412248145,l:'4',m:51.306267359626545,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fno-pie',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.693732640373455,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:36.669774412248145,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fPIC',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.12383930530354,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fPIE',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.206386282448314,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) of `-fPIC` vs. `-fPIE` shows the difference that symbol-interposition makes for **getting the address of non-hidden global variables**:

- `movl    $x, %eax`  5 bytes, `-fno-pie`
- `leaq    x(%rip), %rax`  7 bytes, `-fPIE` and hidden globals or `static` with `-fPIC`
- `y@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax` 7 bytes and a load instead of just ALU, `-fPIC` with non-hidden globals.

Actually loading always uses `x(%rip)`, except for non-hidden / non-`static` vars with `-fPIC` where it has to get the runtime address from the GOT first, because it's not a link-time constant offset relative to the code.

Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) (PIE executables).

---

A previous version of this answer stated that the DATA and BSS segments could move relative to TEXT when loading a dynamic library.  This is incorrect, only the library base address is relocatable.  RIP-relative access to other segments within the same library is guaranteed to be ok, and compilers emit code that does this.  The ELF headers specify how the segments (which contain the sections) need to be loaded/mapped into memory.

Comment: Well, first gives the same error except the relocation type `R_X86_64_PC32` instead of R_X86_64_32S. Second gives an `Error: junk 'CREL' after expression` and `Error: non-pc-relative relocation for pc-relative field`. Removing CREL removes first error but not second.

Comment: Strange. I am able to assemble both examples I gave, using binutils-2.22. Do you have a old version of binutils maybe? The names of special symbols may have changed

Comment: I have Debian Squeeze with binutils 2.20.1-16 and `gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)`.

Comment: are you sure that should not be `@GOTPCREL` instead of `@GOTCREL` ?

Comment: If you don't want to allow for symbol interposition, you can skip the GOT and access it directly with `mov var1(%rip), %rcx`, like GCC does with `-fPIC` for variables with `__attribute__((visibility("hidden")))` https://godbolt.org/z/SyjR8W.  **Dynamic linking can't change the relative displacement between your text and data segments**.   (You can also give your `var1` "hidden" ELF visibility with `.hidden var1` as well as `.globl var1`, like gcc does, if you don't want other shared libraries to be able to link against it, only other `.o` files linked into the shared object you're creating.)

Comment: Sorry for the intrusive edit, but I thought that was more useful to future readers than posting this as my own answer; it would take a long time for down/upvotes to bring the right answer to the top.  I'm 100% certain that code can access .data / .bss variables without going through the GOT, because gcc does that for `-fPIC` for `static int foo;`.  Thus we can be sure that the dynamic linker won't move segments relative to each other.

Comment: @PeterCordes No Problem, you vastly improved my answer

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand. I've already compiled with -fPIC, so what's wrong?

`-fPIC` is a flag concerning the creation of machine code from non-machine code, i.e. which operations to use. In the compilation stage. **Assembly is not compiled, though!** Each assembly mnemonic maps directly to a machine instruction, your code is not compiled. It's just transcribed into a slightly different format.

Since you're writing it in assembly, your assembly code must be position independent to be linkable into a shared library. `-fPIC` has not effect in your case, because it only affects code generation.

Comment: Yes, this is because of my bad english and differencies between it and my native language. In last only one word is commonly used for meaning 'to make a program' and i mechanically used it here...